# For loop working but errors when I convert to reduce function with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

This is working:

```
  const messagesOrganised = {};

  for (const msg of messagesGroupedByName) {
    if (!messagesOrganised[msg.groupBy]) {
      messagesOrganised[msg.groupBy] = [msg];
    } else {
      messagesOrganised[msg.groupBy].push(msg);
    }
  }
```

But when I try and convert it to using the reduce function I get an error:

```
  const messagesOrganised = messagesGroupedByName.reduce((acc, msg) => {
    if (!acc[msg.groupBy]) {
      acc[msg.groupBy] = [msg];
    } else {
      acc[msg.groupBy].push(msg);
    }
  }, {});
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined

Comment: You need to return `acc` So it’s available on the next iteration.

Comment: Well, just don't use `reduce`? There's no advantage to it here.

Comment: @Bergi, _don't use it, because I don't understand it_ - maybe ok when you hitting deadline with a project, but definitely not very good approach here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const messagesOrganised = messagesGroupedByName.reduce((acc, msg) => {
  if (!acc[msg.groupBy]) {
    acc[msg.groupBy] = [msg];
  } else {
    acc[msg.groupBy].push(msg);
  }
  return acc; // return the working object
}, {});
```

`reduce` doesn't track your working object automatically. You need to return something in each iteration of `reduce`, usually your working object. That something will get passed to the next iteration.

Comment: The concept of a "working object" that gets mutated does totally contradict the idea behind `reduce` though :-P

Answer (score 0):

> Please refer to how `Array.reduce()` works:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#How_reduce()_works

```
const messagesOrganised = messagesGroupedByName.reduce((acc, msg) => {
  if (!acc[msg.groupBy]) {
    acc[msg.groupBy] = [msg];
  } else {
    acc[msg.groupBy].push(msg);
  }
  return acc;  // <<<< You need to return accumulated value from callback
});
```

Let me know if this helps.